# i'm using write() to write the results into a file but it does not contain the result of last loop

Tags: python, file, for-loop

briefly, i have a code like:

```
for a in range(3):
 result = 'abcd' + a
 opener = open('file.txt', "a")
 print results
 opener.write(results)
```

my problem is, if i run this code in shell, i can see the printed results,

```
abcd0
abcd1
abcd2
```

but the file contains only,

```
abcd0abcd1
```

the output i want is,

```
abcd0abcd1abcd2
```

any suggestions? i can't find what's wrong with this code...

any help would be really great. thanks in advance

Comment: You really should start the tags with the _language_ you are using. What is it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ashwini Chaudhary's solution is a lot better, consider my answer just as a backgrounder on what went wrong and why it went wrong, and the difference between opening/closing files inside or outside the loop.

File opens and closes should be paired, like here, the file is repeatedly opened, written and closed inside the loop:

```
for a in range(3):
    result = 'abcd' + a
    opener = open('file.txt', "a")
    print results
    opener.write(results)
    opener.close()
```

However, in many cases it's not a good idea to open and close files inside a loop due to the cost of opening and closing a file, so it may be better to open the file before the loop, write the file in the loop, and close it after the loop:

```
opener = open('file.txt', "a")
for a in range(3):
    result = 'abcd' + a
    print results
    opener.write(results)
opener.close()
```

Of course, when the file remains open, and the loop is lengthy, you risk losing data should the program crash, be interrupted or on a reboot of the computer.  In these cases, forcing a flush to the operating system is in many cases a better alternative than repeatedly opening/closing the file:

```
opener = open('file.txt', "a")
for a in range(3):
    result = 'abcd' + a
    print results
    opener.write(results)
    opener.flush()
opener.close()
```

Comment: yeah i have first done the same mistake you wrote on the above. thank you for your advice. it really helped

Answer (score 2):

you may want to try closing the file after you're done writing to it. if python quits before the file closes the last write might not get flushed and hence not written to the file. Just try adding:

```
opener.close()
```

To the end.

Answer (score 2):

use `with()`, so you don't have to worry about opening and closing of file, `with()` automatically closes the file as soon as program moves out of `with` block.

```
with open('data.txt','a') as opener:
    for a in range(3):
        results = 'abcd' + str(a)
        print results
        opener.write(results)
```

Comment: i didn't know about with(). thank you i'll try this one later

Comment: @user1512491 I'll suggest you to learn `with` instead of manually closing files, read more about it [here](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example)